# Insert values append with zero with charcter length 5

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a serial no column in my table. I want to insert values like this:

```
00001  
00002  
.........  
00010  
00011  
........  
00100
```

How can I write a query for this?

Comment: Do you really need those padded zeroes?  Would it be acceptable to just insert a sequence and then be able to query out zero padded numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to store a number and padding with leading zero wont mean anything.

But while displaying you can pad it with leading zero and select number of digit you want using RIGHT() function

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST([serial_number] AS varchar(5)) , 5)
FROM [Table_name]
```

Comment: all result coming 00001 only

Comment: @user3262364 i tried it andn i am getting the correct output.